# Durable Topic Connection Design Opinions Sought

Tags: java

I have a very simple app that is using JMS. The use case that it solves will involve sending small atomic Topic messages.

My first pass at this functionality built one connection to the broker and reused it as needed. However, in reading some of the docs, it seems like hanging onto a connection for reuse potentially hogs resources in the JVM.

So my dilemma is, do I go incur the overhead of building up and tearing down a connection for every message, or do I incur the cost of hanging onto resources that for the most part sit idle.

I know there is no one definitive answer and the real answer is "it depends", but would really like some insight and opinions from others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be aware of both mentioned criteria. The solution is to use a pool of connection. In this case you share the connections and most of the time do not create a new one, as well as pool usually is limited to a specific number of connection (this is my assumption as of how I would implement it) - so that it doesn't take all resources in JVM.

Take a look at [PooledConnectionFactory](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html) related section.

Also decision to keep connections or to recreate them totally depends on your usage scenario. If you plan to send messages regularly - sharing the connection is the right thing to do - since connection and session (I would recommend sharing sessions if possible in a high traffic) creation are quite expensive operations. However if your messages will be sent not that often ( few times per hour? :) ) - it will make sense not to keep alive the idle connection.

Comment: Thank you, that absolutely was the right solution! My load testing is running significantly faster than either create and destroy or to share one single persistent connection. The coding changes in the JAVA app were trivial.